# How do i write a Firebase Storage security rule that only allows write file permissions for auth users to a nested directory and none its parents?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I have the following security rule set for a Firebase Storage bucket:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /avatars/{userId}/{profileId}/{allPaths=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

This works assuming the dynamic subdirectory `userId` matches the `request.auth.uid`.

However, this rule *also* allows that same user to write a *file* to the subdirectory `{userId}` and to write additional directories into `profileId`.

Id like to allow the authenticated user to generate both of the wildcard subdirectories as i have specified, but **ONLY** allow **FILES** to be uploaded into the last directory: `profileId`.

So...

attempting to upload a file into `/avatars/${userId}/{profileId}/file.jpg` should **succeed**.

attempting to write a file into `/avatars/${userId}/file.jpg` should **fail**.

attempting to create a directory in `/avatars/${userId}/{profileId}/directoryName` should **fail**.

attempting to upload a file into `/avatars/${userId}/{profileId}/directoryName/file.jpg` should **fail**.

Is this not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "last nested directory"?

Comment: I just mean the last directory. Ill update the question. Id like the user to be able to generate both of the wild card directories as i have them, but ONY write FILES into the last directory.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's important to understand that [Cloud Storage does not have "directories"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders).  There is no operation to create a "directory".  There are only objects with paths that can have / separators to make it easier for you to organize content.

The reason why users can write to nested paths under profileId is because you are using a trailing recursive wildcard match `{allPaths=**}`, which allows writes under *any possible path* under profileId.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation on wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#match_wildcards) to better understand the behavior.  It sounds like you don't want a recursive wildcard match at all, and instead just a single path segment match, e.g. `{imageId}`.